# from models import Category, Product

Tags: python, django

Problem with "from models import Category, Product"...

```
def ProductList(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    })
```

Comment: Do you fancy telling us what the "problem" is that you are having?

Comment: If your file is in same app then use *from .models import Category, Product* else from appname.models import Category, Product

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about use of point.
You need use from .models import Category, Product.